# Javascript++ (Alternatives to TypeScript)

Tags: javascript

I am unsure if I want to learn TypeScript.

I developed Python during the last 18 years and the mandatory type annotations feel like slowing me down.

But coding pure JavaScript (with the need to support IE11) feels too complicated, since you need to work around missing features.

I know that things like Babel exist. But if I look at the Stackoverflow-Tagtrend, then Babel seems to be fading: http://sotagtrends.com/?tags=[babeljs]

Which alternatives to TypeScript are feasible today?

Comment: I talked to some developers face to face and TypeScript seems today the best way if you want your code to run in the browser.

Comment: It makes sense that Babel is fading, it translate modern JavaScript into old JavaScript, yet as time passes more browsers support modern Javascript. For alternatives to TypeScript see: 
See [Transpilers to Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#transpilers) at Wikipedia. You can find a more complete list at [List of languages that compile to JS](https://github.com/jashkenas/coffeescript/wiki/List-of-languages-that-compile-to-JS) by the CoffeeScript folks, which is probably the best non strongly typed alternative. You may also be interested in Dart.